# Move function to separate file having shared functions and variables

Tags: c

I have a C file which contains multiple functions. The example structure of `mymain.c` is as follows:

```
#include "myheader.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int var1;
    struct var2;

    func1(var1, &var2);
    if(condition)
        func2(var1);
    else
        calc(var1, &var2);

    return 0;
}

static void func1(int var1, struct *var2){

    // do something
}

static void func2(int var1){

    // do something

}

char * func3(char * c){

    // do something
}

static void calc(int var1, struct *var2){
    int myvar = 5;
    char mystring[100]="....";
    func1(var1, var2);
    func3(mystring);
    func2(myvar);
}
```

I want to move the `calc()` and `func3(char *c)` to a separate C file. Following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732959/how-to-move-c-functions-into-separate-file) I moved the two functions  to a `calc.c` file, created a `calc.h` file with the `calc()` signature and did a `#include "calc.h"`in `mymain.c` file. Also included `"calc.h"` in `calc.c`.

The structure of `calc.c` is now:

```
#include "myheader.h"
#include "calc.h"

char * func3(char * c){

    // do something
}

void calc(int var1, struct *var2){
    int myvar = 5;
    char mystring[100]="....";
    func1(var1, var2);
    func3(mystring);
    func2(myvar);
}
```

When I try and build it with NetBeans it shows the following error:

```
In function `main':
mymain.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `calc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:426: recipe for target 'mymain' failed
make[2]: *** [mymain] Error 1
Makefile:504: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: care that you compile both of your .c files, and if you just started using .h files, please read about guard clauses ;)

Comment: Ok, after the edit: Do not include a .c file, never. You should just compile them together like ```gcc file1.c file2.c```

Comment: "_When I try and build it_" - Show the setup of that build.

Comment: @rb-93 please post your header file as well.

Comment: I don't think this question can be salvaged unless all code is deleted, then all actual code from the real project is pasted here.

Comment: In addition to suggestions about making sure you compile and everything, what about the `func1` and `func2` functions? They are still declared `static` in "mymain.c", but are called from the `calc` function in "calc.c". That won't work.

Comment: There are no such types as `struct` or `struct *`.

Comment: It's not possible to post the actual code. Hence the use of an example code. It seems to be creating confusion rather than clarification. Apologies.

Comment: @rb-93 it's ok that you don't post the actual code, but you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is, write something that reproduces the problem and post it. But be sure it *does reproduce the problem before posting it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the `static` functions cannot be seen from other translation units. Remove the `static` declaration, and it will link.

The name of your question also mentions shared variables. If you want to share a variable between translation units, make sure to declare it as `extern` in your header file, and to define it exactly once in one of your source code files.

Comment: @rb-93 then, the most likely reason is that you have forgotten to include calc.c in your project file, and it is not being built.

Comment: Where should I include `calc.c`? I included `calc.h` and `myheader.h` after @Angevil's suggestion.

Comment: @rb-93 Sorry, I didn't mean `#include`-ing it :) Check out your project settings in Netbeans. There must be the "Files" tab in the UI that contains, well, the files. You'll probably see "mymain.c" but not "calc.c" there.

Comment: the whole `static` as typo ... interesting. Do you have a key with the whole word `static`

Comment: @P__J__, this is just the example structure, not the actual code of course. I copied the `calc.c` from the `main.c` and hence the typo.

Comment: @rb-93 but did you check your project structure?

Comment: @RomanDmitrienko, the project contains `calc.c` and `calc.h`.

Comment: @rb-93 at this point it really looks like a project issue. Try making a new project from scratch and including all those files there. Otherwise, it is hard to answer your question without seeing the actual source code and the project file, unfortunately.