# Confusing MACRO and enum definition

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

I was browsing some Route netlink source code.

I wanted to figure out what was the value of RTNLGRP_NEIGH

Source: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rtnetlink.h?v=2.6.35#L550

```
541 /* RTnetlink multicast groups */
542 enum rtnetlink_groups {
543         RTNLGRP_NONE,
544 #define RTNLGRP_NONE            RTNLGRP_NONE
545         RTNLGRP_LINK,
546 #define RTNLGRP_LINK            RTNLGRP_LINK
547         RTNLGRP_NOTIFY,
548 #define RTNLGRP_NOTIFY          RTNLGRP_NOTIFY
549         RTNLGRP_NEIGH,
550 #define RTNLGRP_NEIGH           RTNLGRP_NEIGH
551         RTNLGRP_TC,
552 #define RTNLGRP_TC              RTNLGRP_TC
553         RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR,
554 #define RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR     RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR
...       ...
...       ...
#define RTNLGRP_PHONET_IFADDR   RTNLGRP_PHONET_IFADDR
585         RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE,
586 #define RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE    RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE
587         __RTNLGRP_MAX
588 };
589 #define RTNLGRP_MAX     (__RTNLGRP_MAX - 1)
```

What is this **enum with #define** doing.
What will be the value of **RTNLGRP_NEIGH**? `6 OR 3`

Thanks

Comment: original author should know better than mixing #define and enum like that, looks like a mess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `RTNLGRP_NEIGH` will be 3. You can easily test this with the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* RTnetlink multicast groups */
enum rtnetlink_groups {
        RTNLGRP_NONE,
#define RTNLGRP_NONE            RTNLGRP_NONE
        RTNLGRP_LINK,
#define RTNLGRP_LINK            RTNLGRP_LINK
        RTNLGRP_NOTIFY,
#define RTNLGRP_NOTIFY          RTNLGRP_NOTIFY
        RTNLGRP_NEIGH,
#define RTNLGRP_NEIGH           RTNLGRP_NEIGH
        RTNLGRP_TC,
#define RTNLGRP_TC              RTNLGRP_TC
        RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR,
#define RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR     RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR
        /* ... */
#define RTNLGRP_PHONET_IFADDR   RTNLGRP_PHONET_IFADDR
        RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE,
#define RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE    RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE
        __RTNLGRP_MAX
};
#define RTNLGRP_MAX     (__RTNLGRP_MAX - 1)

int
main()
{
  printf("RTNLGRP_NEIGH = %d\n", RTNLGRP_NEIGH);
}
```

It outputs this:

```
RTNLGRP_NEIGH = 3
```

Since each macro is `#define`d to its own name, the `RTNLGRP_NEIGH` in `main` will be replaced by `RTNLGRP_NEIGH`. But since the expansion is not recursive, it will stop at this point and the program use the `enum` constant `RTNLGRP_NEIGH` which is the fourth and therefore has value 3.

If you are not sure what the preprocessor does, you can always compile with the `-E` switch and look at the pre-processed output.  Compiling the above example with `gcc -E` gives (not showing 840 lines of the `#include`d standard library headers)

```
# 4 "main.c"
enum rtnetlink_groups {
        RTNLGRP_NONE,

        RTNLGRP_LINK,

        RTNLGRP_NOTIFY,

        RTNLGRP_NEIGH,

        RTNLGRP_TC,

        RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR,



        RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE,

        __RTNLGRP_MAX
};


int
main()
{
  printf("RTNLGRP_NEIGH = %d\n", RTNLGRP_NEIGH);
}
```

which is hopefully much less confusing.

The `#define`s mixed into the `enum` definition have no effect to the `enum` definition. It doesn't matter where the `#define`s are located. They could (and probably should) have been placed before or after the definition.

```
/* RTnetlink multicast groups */
enum rtnetlink_groups {
        RTNLGRP_NONE,
        RTNLGRP_LINK,
        RTNLGRP_NOTIFY,
        RTNLGRP_NEIGH,
        RTNLGRP_TC,
        RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR,
        /* ... */
        RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE,
        __RTNLGRP_MAX
};

#define RTNLGRP_NONE            RTNLGRP_NONE
#define RTNLGRP_LINK            RTNLGRP_LINK
#define RTNLGRP_NOTIFY          RTNLGRP_NOTIFY
#define RTNLGRP_NEIGH           RTNLGRP_NEIGH
#define RTNLGRP_TC              RTNLGRP_TC
#define RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR     RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR
#define RTNLGRP_PHONET_IFADDR   RTNLGRP_PHONET_IFADDR
/* ... */
#define RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE    RTNLGRP_PHONET_ROUTE
#define RTNLGRP_MAX     (__RTNLGRP_MAX - 1)
```

The reason they wrote this weired code is probably that they wanted to refactor old code using

```
#define RTNLGRP_NONE          0
#define RTNLGRP_LINK          1
#define RTNLGRP_NOTIFY        2
#define RTNLGRP_NEIGH         3
#define RTNLGRP_TC            4
#define RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR   5
/* ... */
```

to use an `enum` instead. But because existing code might rely on the fact that the identifiers are macros (such as testing `#ifdef RTNLGRP_NEIGH`) they wanted to provide macros with the same value. Note that this approach is flawed, however, because the preprocessor won't know the value of the constant so you cannot do things like `#if RTNLGRP_NEIGH >= 3` which you could, had `RTNLGRP_NEIGH` been `#define`d to `3` literally. So, in essence, their approach combines the disadvantages of using macros (name-space pollution) with those of using `enum`s (not available at pre-processing time).

A maybe more useful pattern I have seen before is to `#define` the constants to actual integers.

```
enum rtnetlink_groups {
        RTNLGRP_NONE
#define RTNLGRP_NONE            0
        = RTNLGRP_NONE,
        RTNLGRP_LINK
#define RTNLGRP_LINK            1
        = RTNLGRP_LINK,
        RTNLGRP_NOTIFY
#define RTNLGRP_NOTIFY          2
        = RTNLGRP_NOTIFY,
        RTNLGRP_NEIGH
#define RTNLGRP_NEIGH           3
        = RTNLGRP_NEIGH,
        RTNLGRP_TC
#define RTNLGRP_TC              4
        = RTNLGRP_TC,
        RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR
#define RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR     5
        = RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR,
        /* ... */
};
```

which will be pre-processed to the following.

```
enum rtnetlink_groups {
        RTNLGRP_NONE

        = 0,
        RTNLGRP_LINK

        = 1,
        RTNLGRP_NOTIFY

        = 2,
        RTNLGRP_NEIGH

        = 3,
        RTNLGRP_TC

        = 4,
        RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR

        = 5,

};
```

Note that here, it is critical that the `#define`s are mixed into the `enum` definition, otherwise we'd get invalid code such as `3 = 3,` instead of the desired `RTNLGRP_NEIGH = 3`.

Oh, and please don't use `__RTNLGRP_MAX` as an identifier. Names containing two adjacent underscores or beginning with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved by the C standard.  Using them in your own code leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Very nice explaination. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The asker is **not** using `__RTNLGRP_MAX` as an identifier themselves. The code in the question is from a system header file.

Answer (score 4):

The value of `RTNLGRP_NEIGH` will be 3 (it is the fourth enumeration constant: `RTNLGRP_NONE` has the value 0, `RTNLGRP_LINK` has the value 1, and `RTNLGRP_NOTIFY` has the value 2).

The `#define` stuff is somewhat weird — it is the sort of thing that's apt to make people want to [stop you using the C pre-processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496418/is-define-banned-in-industry-standards/).

The idea is that it gives you a macro for `RTNLGRP_NEIGH` that can be tested, but the expansion of the macro is the enumeration constant (spelled the same).  There isn't an infinite loop in the expansions because once a macro has been expanded, it is not expanded again while the replacement text is being rescanned.

So, the upshot is that you can write:

```
#ifdef RTNLGRP_NEIGH
   …code using RTNLGRP_NEIGH…
#endif
```