# Should I include a header file multiple times in different files?

Tags: c

Say, for example, that I have header files foo.h and bar.h, which both want to include hello.h, and use macros declared in hello.h. foo.h also already includes bar.h.

Should I include hello.h in both foo.h and bar.h, or just in bar.h? I know it doesn't matter functionally, but I'm not sure what the "standard" is for readability.

Edit: I know how header guards work. I'm not asking from a dependency perspective; I'm asking from a readability perspective.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873206/header-file-included-only-once-in-entire-program

Comment: Always include the immediate dependencies.

Comment: I think it would be better to include hello.h in both foo and bar. That way if someone is reading that one file, they can easily see that a given function comes from hello.h.

Comment: A header file includes another header file if it needs macros or data types defined there. There is very rarely a need for a header file to access function declarations.

Comment: Each header file should be self-contained -- usable without needing any other headers included prior to it.  That's the way the standard C headers work; yours should too.  (These days, that applies to POSIX too; there's no longer any need to include `<sys/types.h>` separately.)  Each header should also be idempotent; there shouldn't be any problem if the header is included multiple times.  Compilers are pretty good about handling this. Use include guards.

Comment: To emphasize what AlexP wrote: what do you mean by "use functions declared in hello.h"?  Your header file should not be defining functions, so in what way are you using functions declared in other headers?

Comment: I clarified: I meant macros, though it's not impossible to use function declarations inside a header file.
@JonathanLeffler Not sure if your comment applies here...? I'm asking from a readability perspective.

Comment: Look up IWYU — Include What You Use. It's a Google project. What I said covers most of what you need to know. If code that uses `foo.h` must have `bar.h` available (that is, `foo.h` itself uses information from `bar.h`, whether types or macros — it probably isn't functions that are used), then `foo.h` should include `bar.h`. If the application code uses functions (types, macros) declared in `bar.h`, it should include it; if it uses functions etc from `foo.h`, it should include that, separately, even though it also includes `bar.h` (but not if it doesn't directly use functions from `bar.h`).

Comment: You can find a lot of my views on this general topic in my answer to [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers/1804719#1804719).  You might find some useful discussion (and useful x-refs) in [Is `#define` banned in industry standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496418/is-define-banned-in-industry-standards/34496517#34496517), though that's primarily about `#define` rather than `#include` per se.

Comment: Helpful as your information is, I already know how the preprocessor works and it's not answering the question.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not helpful to tell you what you need to know.  You need to make headers minimal, self-contained, idempotent.  If you make them so, you will know what you need to do.  Maybe [How to link multiple implementation files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622409/how-to-link-multiple-implementation-files-in-c/15622496#15622496) will help (it covers aspects of header file design); maybe [How to structure `#include` in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276386/how-to-structure-includes-in-c/276588#276588) will help.  Maybe you don't need help since you already know.

Comment: When you say "minimal" is that a yes or no to my question? Please read my question again. I'm not asking how to deal with dependency issues--I'm asking if knowingly putting an unnecessary include would be useful down the road for readability.

Comment: How would including an "unneccessary" include help readability?  `#include <notneeded.h>` seemingly does nothing to help understand later code.

Comment: It's unnecessary in the sense that I know that since foo.h includes bar.h, and bar.h includes hello.h, I don't need to include hello.h in foo.h. However, hello.h is an immediate dependency.
Thank you @EugeneSh., and that does make the most sense. Seems that's the consensus.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the header into preprocessor-ifs. So the compiler will handle it if you include them to often.

```
#ifndef _MYHEADER_
#define _MYHEADER_

// whatever

#endif
```

Comment: Note that you should never invent a name that starts with an underscore and either a capital letter or another underscore.  Such names are reserved for "the implementation" (meaning the C compiler and the writers of the standard C libraries) to use.  By using such names, you are treading on their name space and run the risk of being interfered with.  Use a name such as `MYHEADER_H_INCLUDED` (or `MYHEADER_H`) rather than risk messing with the implementation.  See [§7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) for more information.